# load distributon between various jms provider instances

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ejb, java-ee-5

Producers <--> Consumer

In the above scenario there are lets say 'N' number of producers trying to put a lot of messages in our (Consumer's) JMS queues.

My question is how does the load distribution work in the JMS environments specifically with queues.

I think the JNDI provides sufficient indirection in this case, so all the clients are just looking up some JNDI based queue and connection factory. And any kind of loadDistributor could sit in the between the consumer and the producer to take the incoming messages.

how does it distribute those incoming messages to a farm of JMS providers ( i think we need a farm of them to handle the incoming traffic) but then how do you maintain the synchronized copies of multiple queues.. or do you let any message go into any queue and just process it using MDBs. but how do you guarantee that the 'messages will be processed in the order in which they are received" coz they are all distributed in a bunch of queues...

What is the recommended approach for this kind of 'high-load' environments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue is 'serial' in nature in a way that the messages in it will each be delivered to one receiver. So if you have e.g 2 MBDs listening on the queue, they will each take a message in turn work on it and then get the next one.

For incoming messages, you just put them into the queue one after each other.

I may not completely understand what you are looking into, but it looks at first hand, that 
you need one JMS provider ("messaging hub") that exposes one queue where multiple MDBs (which can live on different hosts) will pick the messages from.

Comment: Thx for your reply Heiko..

Having one messaging hub which exposes one queue and multiple MDBs as message listeners should work fine in normal cases. how abt when millions of messages are coming into the queue per day ?


Will a JEE5 compliant server (like weblogic 11g or Glassfish v3) be able to handle around 3 million messages coming into the queues per day.. 

I was thinking whether we can have multiple queues (each hosted on a separate host running a JMS provider) to handle such high traffic but in that case the queues won't be in sync and hence the message ordering will get messed up.

Comment: Essentially I am looking for industry best practices to handle such high message volumes in a queuing environment... can this be handled a JEE5 server or not ?

Comment: Dunno about WL or GF. HornetQ can (depending on message size and peristence options) do >> 10k messages per second - see https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HornetQ-thePerformanceLeaderinEnterpriseMessaging

Comment: very nice.. thx for the link 
based on these kind of performance metrics, the messaging-hub taking care of the queue and multiple MDBs on different hosts processing those messages .. this architecture should work nicely..